# List table content based on table settings (php / mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have a clue on how to do this, but I was wondering if there's other methods out there, maybe a "best practice" approach.

I have a page that lists a number of datasets that can be found in a "catalogue" table in mysql, like the one below.

```
+----+----------+------+--------------------------+
| id |   name   | type |        listItems         |
+----+----------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | dataset1 | SQL  | id, name, location, type |
|  2 | dataset2 | SQL  | id, gdp, import, export  |
+----+----------+------+--------------------------+
```

The datasets are different, have different structures etc. What I'm trying to achieve is that when I click one of these links, I'm being shown all the records in the respective table. Normally this is a matter of extracting data from a table, but as I mentioned, the data could be different. From the first dataset, I want to list the id, name, location and type field, whereas from the second dataset, I'm looking for id, gdp, import, export and abbreviation. Not only are the columns different, but I don't want to extract all columns, just some.

My initial thought was to have an extra column in the catalogue table (the listItems column), specifying each table's default columns to be extracted. These would be stored in the following format:

```
id, name, location, type
```

Then, when I list items, I identify which dataset I'm using, I'm extracting these values from the catalogue table and then I query the database.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are part way there.

Next, you write PHP code to create the `SELECT` statement using the dataset name and list of columns.

After that, you may realize that you want different formatting: right justified numbers, maybe with commas; anchor tags for values that look like hyperlinks; left justify strings; etc.

How far do you want to take this?  It can all be done in PHP, and there is where most of it belongs.  Your "catalog" is about the only thing to store in the database, and very little is done via SQL.